# Access Form Parts, How to reuse controls across many forms, editing issues

Tags: forms, include

So I have a data base with 8 or 9 forms. Each form has the same 10-15 controls on the top. I'm wondering how I can 'include' these controls, without having to do it on each form. The problem is that anytime these 10-15 controls change, I have to change it 8-9 times, one for each form. I know how to do this using php, e.g. "", and that allows me to only have to edit one file.... but how do I do it with access?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I could use a subform but would prefer not too, because these 8-9 forms include a lot of nested subforms already.

Comment: To clarify: My DB is designed to manage patches. There are 5 forms you have to step thru to answer questions and schedule work. The problem is that the top of these 5 forms is always the same (listing the patch name, release date, add/view attachment buttons, record lock check box, notes button, etc...the stuff common to every form). The issue is that these common controls drift with time, primarily the look of the layout... I'm wondering if I can separate these common controls and then include them, sort the way a public function doesn't have to be written again every time it is used.